# React: class instance in state preventing rerender

Tags: reactjs, components, key, render, react-props

I have the following component

```js
class TreeRenderer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      let tree = new NodeTree(props.values || []);
      this.state = {
        tree: tree,
        currentState: 0,
        value: 0,
      };
      this.add = this.add.bind(this);
      this.pop = this.pop.bind(this);
    }
    add() {
      if(this.state.value == null)
        return;
      this.state.tree.add(this.state.value);  // Not a good pattern, should work on copy if possible
      this.setState({currentState: this.state.tree.length - 1})
    }
  
    pop() {
      if(this.state.value == null)
        return;
      this.state.tree.delete(this.state.value);  // Not a good pattern, should work on copy if possible
      this.setState({currentState: this.state.tree.length - 1})
    }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <TreeStateRenderer state={this.state.tree.states[this.state.currentState]}/>
          <button onClick={this.add}>Add</button>
          <button onClick={this.pop}>Delete</button>
          <input
            type="number"
            id="value"
            value={this.state.value}
            onChange={
              (event) => {
                this.setState({value: event.target.value});
                event.preventDefault();
              }
            }
          />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

I think i understood that calling a method of this.state.tree mutating the object is not a good pattern and does not ensure the re-rendering, but it works in this way.

Now i am using this component in another component.

```js
<TreeRenderer key={ this.state.values } values={ this.state.values } actions={ this.state.actions } />
```

With key props it does re-render correctly, but not without it and i don't understand why.
I did not found the key solution on google/stackoverflow after some days of search so i came back to the documentation and found: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

Since i am not taking props values as it is into state, i wonder why i have this issue and need to use the key props.
By the way, i found many workaround to update class instance in state, the most elegant one being making a copy using object.assign or spread operator, but it does only copy the data and loose its methods.

Thanks for any answer and advices.

Comment: what's structure ```tree``` and ```tree.states```?

Comment: As you can guess from the code given:
tree is an object of class NodeTree and tree.states is a list.

But i don't think this is usefull: The content of key and values in TreeRenderer is the same. But i still needed to set both

Answer (score 0):

i am rewrite with `function component`.

```
const TreeRenderer =(props)=> {
   
      let tree = new NodeTree(props.values || []);
      
      const [tree , setTree] = React.useState(tree);
      const [currentState,setCurrentState] = React.useState(0);
      const [value , setValue] = React.useState(0);
      
     
   const add=()=> {
      if(!!value === false)
        return;
      setTree([...tree,value]);
      setCurrentState([...tree,value].length - 1);
    }
  
   const pop=()=> {
      if(!!value === false)
        return;
      let tempTree= [...tree];
      const indexValue = tempTree.findIndex(x=>x.states == value);
      if(indexValue === -1)
        return;
      tempTree.splice(indexValue,1);
      setTree(tempTree);
      setCurrentState(tempTree.length - 1);
    }
    
    const changeValue =(event)=>{
    setValue(event.target.value);
    }

    return (
      <div>
          <TreeStateRenderer state={tree.states[currentState]}/>
          <button onClick={add}>Add</button>
          <button onClick={pop}>Delete</button>
          <input
            type="number"
            id="value"
            value={value}
            onChange={changeValue}
          />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: It does not work neither answers the question asked:
Why do i need to set "key" props as it has the same content as "values" props

Comment: please add sample code in codesandbox for debugging is better

Comment: This does not affect the rendering as explained. If I log the constructor, it is never called unless i set the key value.
The question stay: why do i have to set the key props when it has the same value as any other props.